# C# LINQ find duplicates and increment

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following table

```
Date/Time                            Value
10/1/2018 2017-05-21 19:30:44.000    11
10/1/2018 2017-05-21 19:30:44.000    12
10/2/2018 2017-05-21 19:31:44.000    9
10/3/2018 2017-05-21 19:32:44.000    8
10/4/2018 2017-05-21 19:33:44.000    12
```

My query currently gets rid of duplicates within Date/Time and Value

```
var res = result.Select(x => new { x.p4.SampleDt, x.p1.Value }).OrderBy(a => a.SampleDt).Distinct().ToList();
```

but need to extend this to have unique Date/Time stamps for duplicate Date/Time stamps.

With linq, I like to find all duplicate date/time stamps (notice how 2017-05-21 19:30:44.000) is duplicated and then increment each entry within the duplicates by 1 millisecond to make it unique. The end result will be only unique date/time stamps

End result would be:

```
Date/Time                                  Value
10/1/2018 2017-05-21 19:30:44.000          11
10/1/2018 2017-05-21 19:30:44.100          12
10/2/2018 2017-05-21 19:31:44.000          9
10/3/2018 2017-05-21 19:32:44.000          8
10/4/2018 2017-05-21 19:33:44.000          12
```

The main thing is I cannot have duplicate dates/time stamps. I need to make then unique somehow by appending to it to make it unique.

Comment: A better sample would be if the third row contained a DateTime which is exactly the 1st/2nd row's DateTime +1 second. But then you had to explain us what should happen

Comment: So what should your end result look like?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes we are trying to clean this up as a work around. Main thing is to have the date/time stamp be unique for duplicate date/time entries.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that it's impossible that another record can have a DateTime value that is one milliscond behind another record, you can use this:

```
var duplicates = table.GroupBy(x => x.SampleDt).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
foreach (var dupGroup in duplicates)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var entity in dupGroup.Skip(1))
    {
        entity.SampleDt = entity.SampleDt.AddMilliseconds(++index);
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that this approach is problematic, you add one millisecond without knowing if the resulting `DateTime` is not already used by another record.

Comment: Potentially you could set the milliseconds to 0 before grouping. This way you'll only get potential collisions if there are more than a thousand in a small time window. It would however mean that potentially things might not come back correctly in time order when their times differ by less than a second. This might be acceptable for the OP though. I note that the sample data already has zeroes for milliseconds on all records so it might already be the case that they are all zero in the real data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. With my code, it could not find the AppMilliseconds function.

Comment: @Chris: setting millis to 0 before grouping would mean you would find duplicates that are not really duplicates which might not be desired. My approach has another drawback if you would execute this "repair" logic more than once. Because then it's possible that new duplicates will get the same DateTime if you add one ms. With every execution (and new duplicate records) it will be more likely that you get new duplicates.

Comment: @NatePet: AddMilliseconds

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry mistyped. I did try with AddMilliseconds. Might you know the namespace for this.  Also will the end result show all the records?

Comment: `SampleDt` is a `DateTime` or a `Nullable<DateTIme`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I got it as such as I had to add .Value as it is a nullable field.            var duplicates = rss.GroupBy(x => x.SampleDate).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

                foreach (var dupGroup in duplicates)
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (var entity in dupGroup.Skip(1))
                    {
                        entity.SampleDate   = entity.SampleDate.Value.AddMilliseconds(++index);
                    }
                }  Says SampleDate cannot be assigned as read only.

Comment: Well, you can't modify a property that is readonly. either give it a public setter or create new instances of your entity class